# Visual Studio Code Workspace settings.json file keeps reverting when I open the application. How do I stop this from happening?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the status bar, for a project, to a different color so I can have a subtle indicator of which project I am on by looking at the status bar.

[This is a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAH7x.png)

1. I open the folder of the project in Visual Studio Code.
2. Press, "ctrl + shift + p".
3. Type and select, "Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)". [Like This.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efxcb.png)
4. I change the contents of the settings.json from:

[Picture of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBR8i.png)

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "statusBar.noFolderBackground": "#212121",
    },
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true
}
```

To:

[Picture of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZKr5.png)

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "statusBar.noFolderBackground": "#212121",
        "statusBar.background": "#7ace63",
        "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#31711e",
    },
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true
}
```

From Here everythings works. The status bar looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAH7x.png) I save and close the application. When I open the folder in VS Code again the settings.json is initialy what I changed it to be, and the status bar starts off how I left it. Then the settings.json reverts back to what it was, and the status bar changes color to the default blue. I know it's saving because if I just open up the settings.json, and not the whole folder, I can see the changes and they do not revert.

Why does the settings.json keep reverting? How can I stop it from reverting, so I can keep the status bar the color of my choice for this specific projec?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am answering my own question. The behavior described above in my question is not the default behavior of VS Code. I had an extension called Peacock, which was causing the described behavior. After removing the said extension, I can alter my "setting.json" file without it reverting on the application's launch.

Comment: Just to link the two ... https://github.com/johnpapa/vscode-peacock/issues/7